# How to reduce the loading time of server data in ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android

What i want to do is: there will be some heading items which will be loaden from "string.xml". When a specific heading item will be clicked, the sub items under it will be loaded from server and immediately expand slowly. If it is clicked again then it will collapse slowly.

What i have done :

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.activities.VocabularyList"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_vocabulary_list">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expnadable_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#A4C739"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft">

    </ExpandableListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

parent_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#A4C739"
        android:textSize="18dp"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

child_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Thsi is child"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.R;
import com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.adapters.ExpandabelListAdapter;
import com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.singleton.MySingleton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ExpandableListView exp_listview;
    ExpandabelListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        exp_listview = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expnadable_listview);

        String[] heading_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heading_items);

        final List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(heading_items));

        final HashMap<String, List<String>> childList  = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for(int i=0; i<headings.size(); i++){
            childList.put(headings.get(i), new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        adapter = new ExpandabelListAdapter(headings, childList, getApplicationContext());

        exp_listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        exp_listview.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, final int groupPosition, final long id) {

                String server_url =  "http://192.168.56.1:8080/voc/topic";
                JsonArrayRequest jsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, server_url, (String)null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                List<String> topicList = new ArrayList<String>();

                                try{

                                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                                        // Get current json object
                                        JSONObject topicObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                        // Get the current student (json object) data
                                        String topic = topicObj.getString("topic");
                                        topicList.add(topic);

                                    }

                                    childList.put(headings.get(groupPosition), topicList);

                                    Toast.makeText(VocabularyList.this,  topicList +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        },

                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                Toast.makeText(VocabularyList.this,  error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                );

                MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArray);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

ExpandabelListAdapter

```
package com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cnpinyin.lastchinese.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by inspiron on 8/24/2017.
 */

public class ExpandabelListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<String> header_titles;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles;
    private Context ctx;

    public ExpandabelListAdapter(List<String> header_titles, HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles, Context ctx) {
        this.header_titles = header_titles;
        this.child_titles = child_titles;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }



    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return header_titles.size();
    }




    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }




    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return header_titles.get(groupPosition);
    }




    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }




    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }





    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String) this.getGroup(groupPosition);

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, null);
        }

        TextView headerTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
        headerTitle.setText(title);
        headerTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String child_title = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
        }

        TextView childHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_header);
        childHeader.setText(child_title);
        childHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I click a specific heading item Toast shows maessage immediately . But does  not expands Items under it. It takes to much time. I can not fix the problem . Help is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For better response time you may use caching mechanism .

You may use Guava for caching in server side. This will shorten the response times of request. Also You could cache in client side on [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html).